# How to figure out if a number is present in a very large dataset

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering as to what would be a suitable answer to the question "Given a very large set of numbers write a service that will return back if a number is present within 500 ms". There would be trillions of numbers. This question was supposed to test my knowledge of scalability and architecture. I answered I would break up the set of numbers into multiple buckets and assign a set to a specific server, very much like a HashMap dividing up it's keys into buckets. In each server, the server would maintain something like a bit array which would mark out if a number is present. He asked me what what if the numbers are very sparse, in which case I will use a balanced binary search tree like red black or AVL tree. I guess there would be multiple solutions to this problem. I was wondering as to what would be the other answers?

Comment: It's not about the answer. It's about hearing how you reason about the problem.

Comment: Totally agree with David Schwartz, this type of question is to test your logical thinking, any solution is acceptable if you can provide a valid reason.

Comment: I think David and PhamTrung are right on mark. I am voting to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's a discussion question, asking for multiple opinions/answers. Not a fit for StackOverflow, as there is no single right answer.

Answer (score 1):

A [trillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillion) is `10^12`. Size of a bigint is `8` bytes. So you have `10^12 * 8 bytes = 7.27` terrabytes.

Now you can easily buy a [8TB disc](http://disctech.com/Hitachi-0F23668-8000GB-SATA-Hard-Drive?partner=1011&utm_source=GoogleBase&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=product&gclid=CLSRxt_d8ckCFUWVfgodF1wBBA) for 500$ and it is not hard to buy a disc for `16TB`. So you can just store all of them on one machine and no need to have a fancy multi-machine stuff. Then you just sort all of them (will take `O(n * log n)` which is approximately `2.8 * 10^13` operations.

On my machine a Go program can execute approximately `10^9` operations in `0.6` seconds, so nothing stops a C program to sort this many integers in `5` hours. This is only done once. Now to return a number you have to do `log 10^12` operations which is less than `50` disk seeks which would be done in microseconds.

Comment: Your estimate for the sorting (which will have to be disk based) looks a little optimistic. But all solutions will suffer this problem. A distributed system might shine here though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree with you. But even if it will take 5 days to sort my numbers, you can still use this solution, because no one have gave the requirement that the system should be ready in 3 hours. The only requirement was that when it is running it has to return the answer in 500ms. In addition you can always parallelize the sort by sorting on k machine and merging stuff together in `O(k * n)`